# Is there any way to identify the events raising after a specific line of code execution in vb.net using VS 2008?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging

Is there any way to identify the events raising after a specific line of code execution in vb.net using VS 2008 ?

i am newbie in vb.net and working to optimize an already running application.
here while i am stepping through the code i found some events get raised after some line of code execution. Eg:

GrdEdit.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "Area"

During execution of this line of code 6 events get raised. I stepped into each line to get the list of events raised.  If i can identify the events other than stepping through the code, i can easily fix the problems

Thanks.

Comment: I hope someone thinking about this at first time :). Don't forget to rate this question.

Comment: What's wrong with stepping through the code? There's a strong argument to be made for single stepping through every single line of code that you write. It seems to be easily justified here.

Comment: Are you trying to skip the first couple events that gte raised or just look at what ones get raised?

Comment: What Cody said above, plus if your problem with stepping through the code is simply that it takes too long, ( like you've got a huge loop to step through, or something) you should look at setting breakpoints and the 'run to cursor' feature in the debugger.

Comment: Hi Chase Ernst. My question is how to find the events get raised in response to a code execution. I know what peterG said above . But i am working to optimize my code and its execution time. In some occasions its raising more events than we expected. Now i need to step through each event to get all raised events, like peterG said . So i am asking, is there any shortcut or easy way to get the list of events that will be affected when a line of code executes ???

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see if some action is causing too many events to be raised, and see a list of events and methods that were triggered, is to use a performance profiler like JetBrains dotTrace performance.

Start the profiler, click the "Start Profiling" button, perform the action, click "Get Snapshot", and then you will be able to find exactly what events are being raised and exactly how many times each of them was raised.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its really a new information. Please share some more tips and tricks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) (commercial, developed by me) to view all function calls and events generated in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Let me check this .